# Runtime error when using gesture recognizer in custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I've asked this question before, but it died without any real answers.

My problem is this:
I want to add a long press gesture to my custom UITableViewCell, but as soon as I add the gesture to my xib-file, the app crashes. I suspect some kind of delegate/reference issue, so if someone has done this before and could explain the process they would go through that would've been great.

If any more info is needed, the link to my old question is here.

[Swift - Adding long press gesture recognizer in custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788001/swift-adding-long-press-gesture-recognizer-in-custom-cell)

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, this issue is really stalling my progress.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift - Adding long press gesture recognizer in custom cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788001/swift-adding-long-press-gesture-recognizer-in-custom-cell)

Comment: @wander are you serious? I even posted it in the question?

Comment: You shouldn't ask the same question twice if the first hasn't received an answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128226/can-i-ask-same-question-again-if-nobody-has-answered